# Library for HttpGet in java

Tags: java, http-get

I have this code:

```
package sig;

import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MyService extends java.lang.Object{

    public JSONObject getLocationInfo( double lat, double lng) {

        HttpGet httpGet = new HTTP("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+lat+","+lng+"&sensor=false");
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            response = client.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
            int b;
            while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
                stringBuilder.append((char) b);
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonObject;
    }
}
```

but it error in `HttpGet` , What library i should use in order to use `HttpGet` , Thank you!

Comment: Search for the class in http://www.findjar.com/. They can tell for an immense amount of classes what JAR they belong too.

Answer (score 0):

Use httpcomponents-client jar.

It has Maven entry as:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Can you tell me, which libraries i should use for that code. It's still error , thank you.

Comment: I gave you name of libraray :  httpcomponents-client.jar. You need to include this jar in your build path. If its maven project use maven entry i paste else download the jar and put it in classpath.